# Как реализовать обращение к API REST на react native?

Tags: react-native

Здравствуйте, подскажите как реализовать POST запросы к REST API в приложении на react native. Было бы хорошо если будут примеры приложения с запросами, так как сам пытался искать ответы, но не смог, лезут ошибки. Пытался вставить код из [примера](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html), но как я понял в примере только чата кода.

Comment: В примере нормальный код, который все и пишут используя rest api. Какой ещё вам нужен код? Если вам надо вынести запросы в редьюсеры (если вы используете redux), то надо смотреть в сторону redux-saga, или самому писать асинхронные методы. В доках redux есть все это. Читайте

Answer (score 1):

А чем вам не подходит пример с оф. документации:

```
function getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
   return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseJson) => {
     return responseJson.movies;
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     console.error(error);
   });
}
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html